# Use of variables embedded in a text in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with something like

> A1: "I like " + str_fruit + " and " + str_vegetable

My VBA code (Word-makro) should insert the corresponding variable:

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim str_fruit as string
Dim str_vegetable as string

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("myExcel.xlsx")

str_fruit = "Ananas"
str_vegetable = "Spinach"

msgbox(oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1"))

Set oExcel = Nothing
Set oBook = Nothing
Set oSheet = Nothing
```

Current output: I like " + str_fruit + " and " + str_vegetable

What I want: I like Ananas and Spinach

I tried different positioning of the quotation marks, but this does not seem to be the issue.

How do I get this working?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, but do you mean this? `oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "I like " & str_fruit & " and " & str_vegetable` - Not sure what your `Msgbox` is doing other than showing the contents of a cell, and your variables aren't even being used anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, still new to VBA. I want the msgbox to show the text of my excel-cell with the variables defined in the code. Without the excel file the solution would be: Msgbox("I like " + str_fruit + " and " + str_vegetable).

Comment: `oBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "I like " & str_fruit & " and " & str_vegetable & "."` Insert this line before the MsgBox. Use the ampersand to concatenate text, + to add numbers. Don't use syntax for addressing range when you address cells (too complicated and too inefficient). Don't use "Hungarian" naming conventions. They were never intended for general use. Don't use "snake names". The underscores aren't needed and don't help.

Comment: @Variatus yeah, that's the same thing I suggested, but it seems he wants to put the variables inside the cell itself, and then use them in code (for some reason)

Comment: You cannot use variables inside the contents of a cell the way that you seem to want to do. Once in the cell, they become literal strings.

Comment: Yes, braX. More context: we have an excel sheet that we fill with text-blocks which are then selected and stitched together by a word-makro. Some variables are defined while the makro is running and these makros need to be added to the text-blocks and then written to a word document. I don't want to change the content of the excel sheet, but i want to insert my variable in the text blocks and write this to a word document (or msgbox, as in this simplified example). Thanks for your effort!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to parse the cell, looking for specific text, and then replace them with the variables in the code, but this is probably a wasted effort... bad design.

Comment: Rethink WHY you are trying to do things that way. There has to be a better alternative.

Comment: @braX ok, too bad this is not possible. It would be quite handy if we could change a text block and its variables simply in the excel sheet rather than going back into the code. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates what i think you want to do, but it has so many flaws it is not recommended as a viable solution:

```
Sub test()

Dim sCell As String
Dim sTest As String
Dim sNewValue As String

Range("A1") = "i like + sTest"

sTest = "Apple"

sCell = Range("A1")

sNewValue = Replace(sCell, "sTest", sTest)
sNewValue = Replace(sNewValue, "+ ", "")

Range("A1") = sNewValue

End Sub
```